# Angular Forms with table

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So I have this requirement, I am trying to submit a form which consists of five records in the form of table. This is what it looks like
table:

[image]

This is the corresponding code:

```html
<form [formGroup]="FeedBack" (ngSubmit)="ADDFeedback()">
  <table class="form-group">
    <tr>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>Q.No</th>
      <th>Question Description</th>
      <th>Answer_ShortTxt.</th>
      <th>Answer_longTxt.</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let obj of QuestionsForSubmittedAnswersArray">
        <td>
          <input
            type="textarea"
            placeholder="{{obj.Section}}"
            [value]="obj.Section"
            class="form-control"
            id="Section"
            formControlName="Section"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="{{obj.QuestionIDId}}"
            [value]="obj.QuestionIDId"
            class="form-control"
            id="QuestionID"
            formControlName="QuestionID"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="{{obj.question}}"
            [value]="obj.question"
            class="form-control"
            id="question"
            formControlName="question"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="{{obj.Answer_ShortTxt}}"
            [value]="obj.Answer_ShortTxt"
            class="form-control"
            id="Answer_ShortTxt"
            formControlName="Answer_ShortTxt"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="{{obj.Answer_LongTxt}}"
            [value]="obj.Answer_LongTxt"
            class="form-control"
            id="Answer_LongTxt"
            formControlName="Answer_LongTxt"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="Feedback"
            formControlName="FeedBack"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**.ts file**

```js
import { ThisReceiver } from '@angular/compiler';
import { FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharepointserviceService } from 'src/Service/sharepointservice.service';
// import { resolve } from 'dns';
// import { SharepointserviceService } from 'src/Service/sharepointservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-business-buendorsement-form',
  templateUrl: './business-buendorsement-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./business-buendorsement-form.component.css']
})
export class BusinessBUEndorsementFormComponent implements OnInit {
  // private service:SharepointserviceService
  SubmittedAnswers:any[]=[];
  QuestionsAndAnswers:any[]=[];
  QuestionsForSubmittedAnswersArray:any[]=[];
  FeedBack!:FormGroup;

  constructor(private service:SharepointserviceService,private fb:FormBuilder) {
    this.FeedBack=fb.group({
      Section:new FormControl(),
      QuestionID:new FormControl(),
      question:new FormControl(),
      Answer_ShortTxt:new FormControl(),
      Answer_LongTxt:new FormControl(),
      FeedBack:new FormControl()
    })
    }
```

I am not able to catch the default value of the input fields and it submits as null and also on clicking on submit all the five records should be console logged but I am able to get only the first.
result/output:

[image]

Comment: You should use FormArray for this type of form. Please check https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Comment: If you can please send the stalkblitz, may be I can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can handle these type of forms using `FormArray`

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uve6mk?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**Component:TS**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  tableForm: FormGroup;

  rowsCount: number = 3;
  get QuestionsAndAnswers() {
    return this.tableForm.get('QuestionsAndAnswers') as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableForm = this.fb.group({
      rows: this.fb.array([]),
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < this.rowsCount; i++) {
      this.QuestionsAndAnswers.push(
        this.fb.group({
          Section: new FormControl(),
          QuestionID: new FormControl(),
          question: new FormControl(),
          Answer_ShortTxt: new FormControl(),
          Answer_LongTxt: new FormControl(),
          FeedBack: new FormControl(),
        })
      );
    }
  }

  ADDFeedback() {
    console.log(this.tableForm.value);
  }
}
```

**Component:Template**

```
<form [formGroup]="tableForm" (ngSubmit)="ADDFeedback()">
  <table class="form-group">
    <tr>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>Q.No</th>
      <th>Question Description</th>
      <th>Answer_ShortTxt.</th>
      <th>Answer_longTxt.</th>
      <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container formArrayName="QuestionsAndAnswers">
        <ng-container
          *ngFor="
            let questionAndAnswer of QuestionsAndAnswers.controls;
            let i = index
          "
        >
          <tr [formGroupName]="i">
            <td>
              <input
                type="textarea"
                class="form-control"
                id="Section"
                formControlName="Section"
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="QuestionID"
                formControlName="QuestionID"
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="question"
                formControlName="question"
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="Answer_ShortTxt"
                formControlName="Answer_ShortTxt"
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="Answer_LongTxt"
                formControlName="Answer_LongTxt"
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="Feedback"
                formControlName="FeedBack"
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's unnecesary "enclosed" the FormArray inside a FormGroup, a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y5q1ms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @Eliseo thanks for your suggestion and learnt new things. But what is the need of a word `fool` in the suggestion. I answered as per the knowledge so far I have. If there are corrections/improvements please guide me & OP in a **FRIENDLY** manner :)

Comment: sorry, I'm not native english, for me a "fool stackblitz" it's only a way to say a "quick sample, with no much code", (generally I made it in the time I write the comment). Apologies if is an incorrect expression or I disturb you -never was my intention-

Answer (score 2):

For table type you have to use FormArray.

Here is the full [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-reactive-form-ysv8vj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)
you can see the output aswell.

[image: output result]

**component.ts**

```
this.FeedBack= this.formBuilder.group({
  Rows: this.formBuilder.array([this.initRows()])
});

initRows() {
 return this.formBuilder.group({
   Section : ['1'],
   QuestionID:['1'],
   question:['test'],
   Answer_ShortTxt:['test'],
   Answer_LongTxt:['test'],
   FeedBack:['test']
 });
}
```

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="FeedBack" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<table class="form-group">          
    <tr>
        <th> Section </th>
        <th> Q.No </th>
        <th> Question Description </th>
        <th> Answer_ShortTxt. </th>
        <th> Answer_longTxt. </th>
        <th> Comments </th>
    </tr>
<tbody formArrayName="Rows"> 
    <tr *ngFor="let obj of FeedBack.controls.Rows.controls;  let i=index;let l=last" [formGroupName]="i">
        <td ><input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="Section" formControlName="Section"></td>
        <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="QuestionID" formControlName="QuestionID"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="question" formControlName="question"></td>
        <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="Answer_ShortTxt" formControlName="Answer_ShortTxt"></td>
        <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" id="Answer_LongTxt" formControlName="Answer_LongTxt"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Feedback" formControlName="FeedBack"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<pre>{{FeedBack.value | json}}</pre>
</form>
```